# MYSQL most recent time

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to grab the most recent time of day. If your data in the database is formatted like this 07:00AM and 08:00pm and 12:00pm.  Sorta like max(). But for the time. In a Mysql query.

Thanks
Eric

Comment: What is the type of your column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best to store it in another format rather than as text. Or at least store it in 24 hour format, then a simple sort would work. You can convert it to 12-hour format when you display the data to the user.

But assuming you can't change your database schema, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(your_time, '%h:%i%p') DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Note that this won't be able to use an index to perform the sorting.

Comment: That also gets the "12:....." numbers wrong. You need to have four sort fields, left=12am, then right(your_time), then left=12pm, then your_time.

Comment: @Ben Lee: Oh yes, I completely forgot that 12:00am should sort *before* 01:00am. Effectively '12:' should be sorted as it if were '00:'. So another way to solve it could be to order by the field after replacing '12:' with '00:'.

Comment: Even with the change you made, that's still going to put anywhere between "12:00pm" (noon) and "12:59pm" at the very top of the list, instead of the middle. You need to put the REPLACE function in both order params, like this: `RIGHT(REPLACE(your_time, '12:', '00:'), 2) DESC, REPLACE(your_time, '12:', '00:') DESC`

Comment: @Ben Lee: I tested it and it seems to work fine. Why do you think that the REPLACE function has to be used in both places?

Comment: @Mark, nevermind, it doesn't. I was just confused for a moment.

Comment: @Ben Lee: I think I have found a better way anyway - by using STR_TO_DATE.

Comment: STR_TO_DATE will be incrediblly slow on a large db tables. You shouldn't store time/dates in text.

Answer (score 1):

You should try STR_TO_DATE() instead if you're using a string. If your times are always formatted as hh:mmAMPM, you can use:

```
MAX(STR_TO_DATE(YourTimeField,'%h:%i%p'))
```

This converts your string to a time, without any need to split it up by substring or anything, so MySQL would then see 09:07AM as 09:07:00 and 02:35PM as 14:35:00, and then would easily be able to determine the MAX of it.

Comment: And I typed that answer too slow :-P

Comment: +1 anyway for noticing that now that only one field is being selected so MAX will work. I didn't update my answer to use MAX after changing it to use STR_TO_DATE.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are dealing with a DATETIME field in your MySQL, you can use this query to get the max time per day:

```
SELECT DATE(YourDateField), MAX(TIME(YourDateField)) FROM YourTable
GROUP BY DATE(YourDateField)
```

When you are dealing with a VARCHAR field, you can try a hack like this:

```
SELECT YourDateField, SUBSTRING(MAX(
    CASE WHEN YourTimeField LIKE '%AM%' THEN '0' ELSE '1' END 
    + REPLACE(YourTimeField, '12:', '00:')
), 2)
GROUP BY YourDateField
```

Comment: he said he is not dealing with a datetime field, but with a string field that has am/pm

Comment: No, he said his field was *formatted* with AM/PM. He did not mention the type of his field.

Answer (score -1):

You can just sort.

```
select time_column from table order by time_column desc limit 1;
```